# java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId

Tags: jsf

using jsf causes a NullpointerException:

```
    WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1858)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsf.list_jsp._jspx_meth_h_form_0(list_jsp.java:112)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsf.list_jsp._jspService(list_jsp.java:86)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

In my lib folder of my glassfish-server and of my dynamic web-project are the following
jars:

- standard-1.1.2.jar
- jstl-jstl-1.2.jar
- jsp-api-2.1
- jsf-impl-2.1.7.jar
- jsf-api-2.2.0-m03.jar

My Bean:

```
@Stateless
@Named 
public class StatelessBean {

    public int getNumberOfMovies() {
        return 42;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPersons() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

My jsf:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link href="../css/basic.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Liste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h:form>
        <h1>Stateless</h1>
        <h:outputText value="Anzahl der Filme: #{StatelessBean.getNumberOfMovies()}" />
        <h:outputText value="Anzahl der Personen: #{StatelessBean.getNumberOfPersons()}" />
    </h:form>   
</body>
</html>
```

The awnsers provided here: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322031/why-did-servlet-service-for-servlet-jsp-throw-this-exception) didnt help.

Dont know how to resolv this.

Comment: I've never seen bean names starting by a caps inside a view... Also you should use `xmlns` instead of `taglib`.

Comment: the bean starting with a caps was a try... without caps its also nullpointerexception. and why xmlns?

Comment: Please read JSF 2.0 books/tutorials/resources if you want to learn JSF 2.0 and not JSF 1.x ones. You're using JSP which is deprecated since JSF 2.0 more than 3 years ago. This indicates that you were reading completely outdated books/tutorials/resources. Also, the presence of `standard-1.1.2.jar` and `jsp-api-2.1.jar` files in your `/WEB-INF/lib` is scary. Your JSF API and impl JARs are also incompatibile in versions. Why exactly did you do that? Reading bad tutorials? Shooting in the dark? Those files would only cause portability trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your view code like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <link href="css/basic.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Liste</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h1>Stateless</h1>
            <h:outputText value="Anzahl der Filme: #{statelessBean.getNumberOfMovies()}" />
            <h:outputText value="Anzahl der Personen: #{statelessBean.getNumberOfPersons()}" />
        </h:form>   
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the way in JSF do declare taglibs.

You will also need to change some configurations in your `web.xml` and rename your file to `yourfile.xhtml` :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<!-- Use prefix mapping for Facelets pages, e.g. http://localhost:8080/webapp/yourfile.jspx -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

To use your bean in EL expressions, you need to change it like this :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class StatelessBean {

    public int getNumberOfMovies() {
        return 42;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPersons() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

**More info :**

- [Custom tags in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-tags-in-jsf-2-0/)

Comment: Doesnt jsf with jsp use taglibs ?

Comment: But that is also not working: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsf/list.jsp(25,43) PWC6228: #{...} not allowed in a template text body.

Comment: Okay with this i get at least an output. But -> no css is working -> my "statelessBean.getNumberOfMovies()" isnt working (no output)

Comment: See edited, I've also modified css path, should work now. For this you could take a look at `h:outputStylesheet` on Google, this is the way!

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-cascading-style-sheets-css-in-jsf/ her i read that there should be generated html code.
hmmm.. i dont get css working. i think its enough for today. thank you :)

Comment: @MarcTigges you should put your css in <web-root>/resources/css/basic.css and use `<h:outputStyleSheet library="css" name="basic.css" />` that should work.

Comment: yeah i read this already and i did it. it isnt working. i will find out somehow why it isnt working. thank you

Comment: Why did you accept the answer if it didn't work for you? This answer didn't cover all problematic aspects either.

Comment: @BalusC I'm not as expiremented as you but your comments will be appreciated if I could make this answer more precise. For the CSS, this is not directly related to the question but with this pointers this _should_ work properly.

Comment: "This answer didn't cover all problematic aspects either." which not? i accepted cause my original problem was solved -> the nullpointerexception. i just dont get output for my bean and css not working but that wasnt part of my question so i thought its legal to accept

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the call to getNumberOfMovies.  JSF silently adds the word 'get' and the brackets '()' to the value in your html.  The idea is that you write getters and setters and then just name the property and JSF calls the appropriate one.

```
<h:outputText value="Anzahl der Filme: #{statelessBean.numberOfMovies}" />
        <h:outputText value="Anzahl der Personen: #{statelessBean.numberOfPersons}" />
```

However, this invokes a propertyNotFoundException.  It may also be the cause of your null pointer but I'm not sure.