# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException

Tags: hibernate, servlets

Solution for this ...

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>     at com.example.servlet.Operation.doPost(Operation.java:52)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

please give me solution for this error

Comment: it looks like hibernate is not on your classpath. are you using osgi?

Comment: Add hibernate jars to the classpath

Answer (score 1):

Missing Hibernate jars

Use below dependency if using Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

or manually add jars to the classpath of the project below link should help

[Why did Servlet.service() for servlet jsp throw this exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322031/why-did-servlet-service-for-servlet-jsp-throw-this-exception)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.0.0.Final) into class path. This jar contains the required class [`org.hibernate.HibernateException`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/HibernateException.html)

If you are using eclipse IDE then [this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29) may help you in adding the jar to the class path.

---

As the name suggests `ClassNotFoundException` in Java is a subclass of `java.lang.Exception` and Comes when **Java Virtual Machine** tries to load a particular class and **doesn't found the requested class in classpath.**

Another important point about this Exception is that, It is a **checked Exception** and you need to provide explicitly Exception handling while using methods which can possibly throw `ClassNotFoundException` in java either by using try-catch block or by using throws clause.

[Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html)

```
public class ClassNotFoundException
      extends ReflectiveOperationException
```

Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:

- The forName method in class Class.
- The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader .
- The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.

but no definition for the class with the specified name could be found.