# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

My .jsp file:

```
<%@page import="lm.BookBean"%> 
<%@page contentType="text/html"%> 
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%> 
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%> 
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %> 
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    <title>Library Settings</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <jsp:useBean id="book" scope="page" class="lm.BookBean" /> 
    <%book.addSettings(); %> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

and my BookBean is:

```
public int addSettings() { 
  System.out.println("step 1"); 
  Connection con=null; 
  PreparedStatement ps=null; 
  try { 
    con=Database.getConnection(); 
    ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into settings values (?,?,?)"); 
    ps.setInt(1, no_of_books) 
    ps.setInt(2, day_renewal); 
    ps.setInt(3, fine); 
    ps.executeUpdate(); 
  } catch(Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
  } finally { 
    Database.clean(con, ps); 
  } 
  return (Integer) null; 
}
```

I have face this kind error:

> HTTP Status 500 - type Exception report message description The server encountered an internal error ()

that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

The exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /LRapplication/pages/library_settings.jsp 
   at line 17 <jsp:useBean id="book" scope="page" class="lm.BookBean" /> 
   <jsp:setProperty name="book" property="*"/> <%book.addSettings(); %>   
   Stacktrace:   
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:519)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:428)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:410)
    ... 
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)   root 
      cause 
    java.lang.NullPointerException 
    lm.BookBean.addSettings(BookBean.java:144) 
    org.apache.jsp.LRapplication.pages.library_005fsettings_jsp._jspService(library_005fsettings_jsp.java:87)   
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260) 
    ...
```

Comment: Look it Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322031/why-did-servlet-service-for-servlet-jsp-throw-this-exception

Answer (score 1):

You've had horrible formatting in your stacktrace. Now that it's slightly formatted, find the following content:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
lm.BookBean.addSettings(BookBean.java:144)
```

Inspect line 144 of BookBean.java. You're accessing a null object there.